# react-native fails on bundling

Tags: react-native, npm

I hope you can help me with an issue I encountered today and I am totally lost at the moment. I have a react-native project going and yesterday everything was working just fine, but today I was trying to start up the bundler, simulator and so on, but got a strange error instead that leaves me totally in the wild with no real clue where to get into this.

#### Error message

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected { (52:36)
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1749:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseClassBody (/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2436:8)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseClass (/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2406:8)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1843:19)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlockBody (/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:2268:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1778:8)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1673:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:7305:37) [/Users/michel.engelen/...<patchToProject>.../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Button.js]
```

This message pops up in the terminal when entering `npm start -- --reset-cache` and `react-native run-ios` afterwards.

#### Project settings / packages installed

Here are my dependencies inside the `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "npm": "6.3.0",
  "prop-types": "15.6.2",
  "react": "16.3.1",
  "react-native": "0.55.4",
  "react-native-fontawesome": "5.7.0",
  "react-native-remote-svg": "1.2.0",
  "react-native-splash-screen": "3.1.1",
  "react-navigation": "2.11.2",
  "react-redux": "5.0.7",
  "redux": "3.7.2",
  "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
  "redux-undo": "1.0.0-beta9-9-7"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "7.0.0-beta.56",
  "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "0.2.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
  "eslint": "5.3.0",
  "eslint-config-google": "0.9.1",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "2.13.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "7.10.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.2.1",
  "redux-devtools-extension": "2.13.5"
},
```

I did not specify ranges on them because that nearly always resulted in strange errors with other bundling issues (not this time though).

#### efforts to solve this (`til now)

1. `rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json`
2. upgrading the packages
3. removing `jest` from the dependencies
4. `rm -rf ios/ android/ && react-native eject`
5. reset the branch to a commit in the past that was working for sure
6. I even used `yarn` instead of `npm` during all of these steps to see if it has any impact on the outcome

I even tried to reboot the MacBook, but nothing worked up until now.

I seriously hope that somebody can help me with this, because otherwise I would probably have to redo everything, which would take me a lot of time.

Comment: Delete all the node modules and try `yarn` instead of `npm`.

Comment: Well, I should have told you that as well, but I did use `yarn` as well ... I will update my question